# how do I do a URL that is 2 layers

Tags: magento2, page-builder

For example for this page there is a /questions/ask

I know how to do a simple URL with a Store direct URL line below not sure how to make one with 2 slashes.

simple
a href="{{store direct_url='test'}}">Test

Answer (score 0):

In page builder, you have the option to choose URL, Product, Category, or Page

You will put your entire URL in the URL selection

[image]

So for example: In the URL box you can put https://www.example.com/questions/ask